# Can Brain.js do a regression?

Tags: node.js, regression, brain.js

I'm trying to define a price for websites using some attributes like numbers of visists, categories, age ...
But the things is lineare regression is not accurate enought, so I would like to know if brain js can be train to do some sort of regression ?

I have a list of websites with all attributes and their price to train the NN and in my end just by sending the attributes I want the NN to return me the price

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://fantashit.com/brain-js-to-be-used-for-regression/

Comment: I tried this and this doesn't seem to work, by lowering the errorThresh it just seem to lower the end result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I sorted out your regression possibility in `brain.js` through a `github` issue.

All you have to do is to represent each of your `input` and `output`  between a range of `[0-1]`

---

**First combination would be of age i-e from 0 to 1**

let `0.10` means `10` years old and remember that `age cannot exceed more than 1.0`

---

**Second combination would be of visits per hours/day/week from 0 to 1**

let `0.25` means `25` visits per hour or you can represent `0.25` based on your own need of visits per hour/day/week etc.

---

**Third combination would be of different category, each having different value from 0 to 1**

let `0.01` represents first category for example `sports`.

---

**Fourth combination would be of output i-e `price` each having different value from 0 to 1**

let `0.30` represents `price` equal to `30` dollar.

---

## Code

```
const brain = require('brain.js');

const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

network.train([
        // [age, visits, category]     [price]
        
  { input: [0.10, 0.20, 0.40], output: [0.30] }, // 1 input
  { input: [0.10, 0.50, 0.50], output: [0.60] }, // 2 input
  { input: [0.10, 0.40, 0.60], output: [0.20] }, // 3 input
  { input: [0.10, 0.40, 0.50], output: [0.50] }, // 4 input
  { input: [0.10, 0.30, 0.30], output: [0.90] }, // 5 input
  { input: [0.10, 0.70, 0.30], output: [0.70] }  // 6 input
]);


//multiply answer by 100 to get price value 
const output = network.run([0.10, 0.50, 0.60])*100;

console.log(`Price: ${output}`); // output lies between 2 and 3 input         
                                                          i-e 38.1325
```

Comment: Yea it work thanks ! but the thing is strangly I try another methode that consist as using price as output class and so it's not a regression and it's kind of limited, but it's way more accurate, I do not have that much exeprience in machine learning so do you think I should stay with a regression ?

Comment: if it is limited then in my opinion you should not use your method and do check `ml5` javascript library it is more known for `regression`.

Comment: Okey, but ml5 is a front-end and I need to work in a backend nodejs env :(

Comment: then `tensorflow.js`

Comment: The problem is you don't always know the highest or lowest value to map from `0` to `1`. For example the price of a house.